# Grunt error 'Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task' when building Cordova Application

Tags: android, cordova, gruntjs

I been trying to use Cordova with Dojo (Javascript) to create an Android application.  I found this webpage that shows a simplified process:  http://www.gauntface.co.uk/blog/2013/07/18/cordova-web-best-practices/.

However, I'm currently getting this error when I try to run "grunt build" in my directory:
    $ grunt build 
    Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
    Cleaning .tmp...OK
    Cleaning ../www/.htaccess...OK
    Cleaning ../www/404.html...OK
    Cleaning ../www/config.xml...OK
    Cleaning ../www/favicon.ico...OK
    Cleaning ../www/index.html...OK
    Cleaning ../www/robots.txt...OK

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Going through app/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

```
concat:
{}

uglify:
{}

cssmin:
{}

Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task

Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
File ../www/404.html created.
File ../www/index.html created.

Done, without errors.

Running "svgmin:dist" (svgmin) task

Done, without errors.

Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Minified 0 images (saved 0 B)

Done, without errors.

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task

Running "compass:server" (compass) task

Done, without errors.

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
Copied 1 files

Done, without errors.
```

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.

> > No "concat" targets found.
> >     Warning: Task "concat" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

According the article, the output from the build should go into the www directory, which appears to be happening, but because of the failure, only 4 files are put into that directory:
    $ ls ../www
404.html  index.html

I've tried looking up the errors above.  Mostly what I've found is a series of closed bug reports, without any resolution.  Most of the reports were for yeoman webapp, I'm actually using yeoman cordova since I'm trying to create a mobile application with Dojo/Javascript.

As the error message states, I have done "grunt build --force", but not all the files are copied into the www directory as expected, thus a working application is not created.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the errors above?

Thanks,

Harlan...

Answer (score 2):

Reading this bug on yeoman: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/247 it suggests that you need a usemin block.

Now - not being an expert, but I believe a usemin block is a way of concatenating a set of files and then minifying the results.

Like so:

Which judging by your html, you don't have. So I'd try the following:

1.) Ensure you have the latest set of packages for yo and generator-webapp

```
npm cache clean
npm update
npm update -g
```

Start an new project and move your files over as you had before and see if the problem goes away from a fix in the project

2.) Add a usemin block for dojo or an empty js or css file

3.) use the Dojo genetor instead of your current generator and follow the instructions on the blog post to get it work with the cordova cli.

Comment: In my case it was indeed no usemin block in my html.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't installed grunt-contrib-concat (check also grunt-contrib-[uglify|cssmin]).

FYI grunt-autoprefixer doesn't support concatenation since v0.6, so you have to use grunt-contrib-concat to merge your CSS files into one and then prefix the one via grunt-autoprefixer.

Comment: Hi Dmitry.  Thank You for taking the time to comment.  I installed grunt-contrib-concat before posting; I just tried installing it again.  Didn't make a difference.  I also installed the uglify and cssmin.  Again, no change.  I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: Show the config please. ‘Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task File ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.’ message is the successful message, so the problem is that you have no targets at concat task (as well as at uglify or cssmin). Grunt has nothing to do with that and show you the error. Have you specified your files in HTML? https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blocks

Comment: Here is my HTML file. All this seems to work when run through Apache.  Any ideas or suggestions?  Thanks!!!   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OpenEmergency 2(Dojo Boilerplate) cc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/app.css" />
    
    <!-- prevent cache -->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  
</head>
<body class="claro">
<script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true, async: 1"></script>
     <script src="run.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>